# Classification of fixed points in 4D system of autonomous ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

Let's say I have a 4D system of autonomous ODEs

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\dot{u} = f(u,v,w,z)\\
\dot{v} = g(u,v,w,z)\\
\dot{w} = h(u,v,w,z)\\
\dot{z} = i(u,v,w,z)\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Let $\dot{x} = (\dot{u}, \dot{v}, \dot{w}, \dot{z})$ and $x^{*} = (u^{*}, v^{*}, w^{*}, z^{*})$ be a fixed point. Therefore, Taylor's expansion of the RHS yields

\begin{equation}
\dot{x} = f(x^*) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} |_{x^*}(x - x^*)+ ... = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} |_{x^*}(x - x^*) ...
\end{equation}

By interpreting $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} |_{x^*}$ as a Jacobian and setting $\delta x = x - x^*$, we get a linearized system

\begin{equation}
\dot{\delta x} = J^{*}\delta x
\end{equation}

Let's say the characteristic polynomial of the characteristic equation $det(\lambda I - J^{*})$ is 4th degree polynomial with 4 roots such that $\lambda _{1,2}$ are real and $\lambda _{3,4}$ are complex. How do I classify this fixed point?

Comment: What kind of classification are you looking for? Just stable/unstable, or something finer? (In any case, you need to start by looking at the signs of the real parts of the eigenvalues.)

Comment: I would love to get a concrete classification. So far, I drew $u,v$ isoclines and tried to classify points of intersection by plotting time series of the system and comparing the results with my eigenvalues. The results: $Re(\lambda_{1}) >0, Re(\lambda_{2}) < 0$. I concluded this is a saddle-node. How do I interpret $\lambda_{3,4}$ being complex? Are they reffering to $(w,z)$? Not mathematically rigorous at all, but I'm struggling to find information on how to do that as all the literature focuses on 2D autonomous ODE's for the most part.

Comment: No, it's not necessarily $(w,z)$. You should change to a new coordinate system, say $(h_1,h_2,h_3,h_4)$, with the axes aligned with the eigenspaces. Then $\lambda_{3,4}$ tell you what the linearized system is doing in the $(h_3,h_4)$ plane.

Comment: Is it correct to say that if my eigenvalues are the following: 1) $a_{1}$; 2) $-a_{2}$; 3, 4) $a_{3} +- bi$, then it is a saddle-focus?

Comment: I don't really know what the standard terminology is in 4 dimensions (or if there even is a standard terminology for all the different cases).

Comment: It's fine. Thank you for your answers! I'll try to find literature on that topic.